# What is the song that Drocell sings?

Tags: music, black-butler

In *Kuroshitsuji*, they often sing a song that ends on "my fair lady," [see here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQv8Mq_H55s).

It sounded really familiar to a song that I've heard before in several other languages, but I can't find the name or the origin of this song.

What is the name of this song?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That song is the nursery rhyme "London Bridge is Falling Down," or simply "My Fair Lady."

This version that is sung seems to be a variation on [the one quoted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge_Is_Falling_Down#Lyrics) by [Iona and Peter Opie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iona_Opie) in 1951.

> London ba shi o chi ru, o chi ru, o chi ru
>   London ba shi o chi ru, My Fair Lady
>   (London Bridge is falling down / Falling down, Falling down. / London Bridge is falling down / My fair lady.)
>
> Tetsu to hagane de tsukure, tsukure, tsukure.
>   Tetsu to hagane de tsukure, My Fair Lady
>   (Build it up with iron and steel, / Iron and steel, iron and steel, / Build it up with iron and steel, / My fair lady.)
>
> Tetsu to hagane ja magaru, magaru, magaru.
>   Tetsu to hagane ja magaru, My Fair Lady
>   (Iron and steel will bend and bow, / Bend and bow, bend and bow, / Iron and steel will bend and bow, / My fair lady.)
>
> Kin to gin de tsukure, tsukure, tsukure.
>   Kin to gin de tsukure, My Fair Lady
>   (Build it up with silver and gold, / Silver and gold, silver and gold, / Build it up with silver and gold, / My fair lady.)
>
> Kin to gin ja nusumareru, nusumareru, nusumareru.
>   Kin to gin ja nusumareru, My Fair Lady
>   (Silver and gold will be stolen away, / Stolen away, stolen away, / Silver and gold will be stolen away, / My fair lady.)
>
> Rou to ishi de tsukure, tsukure, tsukure.
>   Rou to ishi de tsukure, My Fair Lady.
>   (Build it up with bricks and mortar, / Bricks and mortar, bricks and mortar, / Build it up with bricks and mortar, / My fair lady.)
>
> Rou to ishi ja kuchihateru, kuchihateru, kuchihateru.
>   Rou to ishi ja kuchihateru, My Fair Lady.
>   (Bricks and mortar will not stay, / Will not stay, will not stay, / Bricks and mortar will not stay, / My fair lady.)